# include view helpers for view being called from a Service object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an object that prebuilds a cached page. I call it like this:

```
str = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths['app/views'])
                          .render(partial: 'item_generator/item_with_modal',
                                  locals: { item: @item, format: 'div',
                                            create_external: @create_external,
                                            view_file: @view_file })
```

How would I make it so that ApplicationHelper would be included so that helpers could be called?

I currently have something like:

```
<%=raw ApplicationController.helpers.js_clean(item.detail) %>
```

but would rather just have:

```
<%=raw js_clean(item.detail) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `extend` to include the helpers in the `ActionView::Base` instance:

```
str = ActionView::Base.new(Rails.configuration.paths['app/views']).tap do |v|
  v.extend(ApplicationController.helpers)
end.render(
   partial: 'item_generator/item_with_modal',
   locals: { 
     item: @item, 
     format: 'div',
     create_external: @create_external,
     view_file: @view_file 
   }
)
```

Comment: hmm... interesting ... but I'm getting this error: 2017-06-02T22:41:44.599Z 39572 TID-ox68oqspg WARN: TypeError: wrong argument type ActionView::Base (expected Module)